# Remove internal node In XSLT

Tags: xslt

I want to to remove internal node using xslt.

Input :

```
<row>
   <entry align="left" namest="3" valign="middle">
       <p type="Table Head">
          <c type="_Table Green grid ALL">Medium–low</c>
       </p>
   </entry>
</row>
```

Output should be:

```
<row>
   <entry align="left" namest="3" valign="middle">
       <p type="Table Head">
          Medium–low
       </p>
   </entry>
</row>
```

I used `<xsl:copy-of>` to perform this. But it copies with `<c>`.

The thing I want to do is remove `<c>` node. I am using XSLT 2.0

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly. What have you investigated so far for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try It

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
</xsl:copy>        
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="c">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @Xpathforlife this work:-


 http://www.utilities-online.info/xsltransformation/?save=38a2a8fc-74c1-4e95-90e8-91335b723e09-xsltransformation

Comment: This works well

Comment: How can i remove the space before and after the text. `<p type="Table Head"> Medium–low </p>`

Comment: Add `<xsl:strip-space elements="*">` to remove any excess whitespace. Otherwise the spaces before and after the `c` tag will be included.